# Meteor: Reactive markers with mapbox

Tags: meteor, mapbox

I'm currently trying to reactively show markers on a Mapbox map. My approach was to observe a collection and while doing so, create a GeoJSON object. Changes in that particular object do not reflect on the map however.

```
var featureArray = [];
CollectionName.find({}).observe({
  added: function(item) {
      featureArray.push({
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [+item.location.coordinates[0], +item.location.coordinates[1]]
        },
        properties: {
          _id: item._id,
        }
      });
  },
  changedAt: function(newDocument, oldDocument, atIndex) {
    //..
  },
  removed: function(oldDocument, atIndex) {
    //..
  }
});

var CollectionGeoJSON = {
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',
  'features': testmarkers
};

var markers  = L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(CollectionGeoJSON);

// add cluster markers and add them to map
```

My idea was to manually add/remove/change the markers on the client (as changes are synced to the server anyway), however also no success here as I'm not sure how to do that using the Mapbox API.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/jn5xpnRpFmCeJiyqs/Mapbox) example, showing this.

The reactivity is created by calling `template.autorun` in the `onRendered` callback.  The `template.autorun` callback is triggered by any changes to the results of `Cities.find()`, and updates the map with `.setGeoJSON`

```
this.autorun(function () {
  if (Mapbox.loaded()) {
    geojson = Cities.find().fetch()
    view.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
  }
});
```

In this example the contents of the Cities collection are already in the correct format to be passed to `.setGeoJSON`, but if you prefer you could have a different Colleciton schema, and create the list in this format within the `template.autorun` callback.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've changed my Collection schema accordingly and that did the trick. I had already made use of template.autorun within the onRendered callback; the conversion seemed to be the problem.